# Crontab is failing to execute Python script

Tags: python, json, ubuntu, automation, cron

We are encountering a problem with the crontabs on a Ubuntu 12.04 LTS server.

**Goal:** *A automated python script with saved .json output*

**Purpose:** *This .json needs to be imported in a MongoDB Database (automated as well)*

**Setup:** *Ubuntu-server with 12.04 LTS*

**Note:** *The webcrawler code contains: #!/usr/bin/python one the very first line*

Let's start at the beginning. All we need to do is automate a python script using crontab. We have a webcrawler written in Python script. The output will be saved in a .json file. This has been determined / coded within the script. 
We need this crawler to run multiple times a day in order to use the .json file for other purposes.

***This is what we've tried so far:***

We started to make the .py file executable by using :

```
$ sudo chmod -x ./crawler.py
```

Then we made a cronjob using:

```
$ sudo crontab -e
20 16 2 1 5 /home/user/crawler.py
```

Now, we checked if we got a right output. A .json file on the server is what we need?
We used:

```
$ sudo grep CRON /var/log/syslog
```

**Our output :**

```
Jan  2 15:17:01 ubuntu-vm CRON[20062]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Jan  2 16:17:01 ubuntu-vm CRON[20927]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Jan  2 16:20:01 ubuntu-vm CRON[20933]: (root) CMD (python /home/user/crawler.py)
Jan  2 16:20:01 ubuntu-vm CRON[20932]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
```

Discard output? No! We need that output! We used google and other stackoverflow-posts to check for solutions on the "No MTA installed etc".
So we came up with several links and we did two things. Install postfix (MTA) and edited the crontab.

*no configuration *

```
$ sudo apt-get install postfix
35 16 2 1 5 /usr/bin/python /home/user/crawler.py
```

**Our output:**

```
Jan  2 16:35:01 ubuntu-vm CRON[22459]: (root) CMD (/usr/bin/python /home/user/crawler.py)
Jan  2 16:35:01 ubuntu-vm CRON[22458]: (root) MAIL (mailed 1 byte of output; but got status 0x004b, #012)
```

Finally, we tried one more thing by adding /dev/null 2>$1 to the crontab in order to skip the "MTA-thingy".

```
$ sudo crontab -e    
52 16 2 1 5 /usr/bin/python /home/user/crawler.py /dev/null 2>$1

Jan  2 16:52:01 ubuntu-vm CRON[22494]: (root) CMD (/usr/bin/python /home/user/crawler.py /dev/null 2>&1)
Jan  2 16:52:01 ubuntu-vm CRON[22493]: (root) MAIL (mailed 1 byte of output; but got status 0x004b, #012)
```

So, at the end? We can't figure out what we are doing wrong. We just need a python script to be automated and generate a .json file as output. Our question is, could someone take a look at this post and help us? We would appreciate it very much! :)

**Edit 1**
@Digisec
@Alex Martelli

The reason why we tried /dev/null 2>&1 was, after the crontab we encountered an error about the MTA, Mail Transfer Agent, on the syslog. So we came up with this in order to skip this error. But apparently it would not make a difference. In fact, it might not have any function in this cronjob at all. We don't know what /dev/null actually does. We just need a crawler.py to run smoothly per time unit.

You will probably notice that the json format is totally different. In fact, this crawler is made for data.txt and **NOT** data.json. But some people told us it would not make a difference. But in fact it should be .txt. But we need the data in MongoDB. And MongoDB doesn't work with txt.

Thanks for your comments !

```
def spider_Products():
    print('Loading products...')
    dataset = open('data.json', 'w')
    for page in bbvProductpages:
        source_code = urllib.request.urlopen(page)
        main_data = BeautifulSoup(source_code.read())
        link = main_data.findAll('div', {'class':'listRow'})
```

**Edit 2**
@Digisec

```
ubuntu-0864947@ubuntu-vm:~$ sudo bash ./crawler.py
./crawler.py: line 2: __author__: command not found
./crawler.py: line 3: import: command not found
./crawler.py: line 4: import: command not found
from: can't read /var/mail/bs4
./crawler.py: line 8: url: command not found
./crawler.py: line 10: bbvSubmenus: command not found
./crawler.py: line 11: bbvProductpages: command not found
./crawler.py: line 12: bbvSublevels: command not found
./crawler.py: line 13: /html/product/listing.html?navId=2436&bgid=8148&tk=7&lk=9309,: No such file or directory
./crawler.py: line 14: /html/highlights/page.html?hgid=658&tgid=972&tk=7&lk=9302,: No such file or directory
./crawler.py: line 15: /html/product/listing.html?navId=1216&tk=7&lk=9529,: No such file or directory
./crawler.py: line 16: /html/product/listing.html?navId=1218&tk=7&lk=9530,: No such file or directory
./crawler.py: line 17: /html/product/listing.html?navId=1222&tk=7&lk=9531: No such file or directory
./crawler.py: line 18: ]: command not found
./crawler.py: line 20: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./crawler.py: line 20: `def spider_Mainpage():'
```

Path: /home/user/crawler.py

The reason for /dev/null :
http://ubuntu.aspcode.net/view/635400140124705175345096/cron-info-no-mta-installed-discarding-output-error-in-the-syslog

**Edit 3** @Digisec

I changed the first line to

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

just like u wanted me to do. 
Execution of the .py file:

```
user@ubuntu-vm:~$ python ./crawler.py
File "./crawler.py", line 73
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xe2' in file ./crawler.py on line 73, but no 
encoding declared; see http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for details
user@ubuntu-vm:~$
```

Can you see what we are missing?

Comment: What happens if you run the script exactly like you have it in cron ? What is the error then ? Also it is `2>&1` if you are trying to redirect stderr to stdout and not `$1`

Comment: `chmod -x` **removes** the executable bit -- was that a typo for `chmod +x` perhaps?  Anyway, can you show the gist of the script -- how does it determine what json file to write, what does it write (if anything) to stdout and/or stderr, how did you observe that the json file supposed to be written to was not, etc, etc...?

Comment: @Babycakes247 I still don't know what error you get if you run the script from the terminal straight out. Also, on linux the extension does not matter.

Comment: First off, add a **shebang** to the beginning of that script.
`#!/usr/bin/env python`
You are trying to run the script from bash and bash is assuming it's a bashscript, it is not.

Comment: Just a note: file extensions have nothing to do with the content. You can have `data.txt` that contains json-valid data, and use it to insert to mongo.

Comment: add `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` in the beginning of your file